# Ошибка со свёрточной нейронной сетью

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Начал заниматься нейронными сетями и решил сделать свою архитектуру нс.

Вот мой код:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
inputShape = (32, 32, 3)
chanDim = -1
    # CONV => RELU => BN => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding="same",
  input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  # first set of (CONV => RELU => CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# second set of (CONV => RELU => CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  # first set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# second set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
# return the constructed network architecture
print ("End")
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по ошибке вы подаёте на вход НС картинки в оттенках серого, а она ожидает картинки с тремя цветовыми каналами

Comment: inputShape = (32, 32, 3) здесь же три канала

Comment: Здесь три, а сколько каналов в тензорах, которые вы подаёте на вход сети

Comment: Я пока новичок в этом деле, но я ещё не показывал нейронке свой датасет, я только её компилирую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько комментариев к вашему коду:

после первого применения слоя `Flatten()` - нет смысла делать это снова после `Dense` слоёв:

```
# first set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# second set of FC => RELU layers
### model.add(Flatten())  <--- эту строчку стоит убрать / закомментировать
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

далее если вы ожидаете в выходном слое более одного юнита и используете функцию активации `"softmax"`, то в качестве функции ошибки/потери следует использовать `"categorical_crossentropy"`.

"binary_crossentropy" - используется для случаев **бинарной** классификации вместе с функцией активации `sigmoid` в выходном слое.

поэтому модель следует компилировать так:

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["acc"])
```